# how to call layout's view from non activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a requirement that I have to call layout's view(Button,Text) like that from non Activity.

```
For Example:

 1.Utils.java->which is core java class
 2.calling setContentView(R.layout.loing);
 3.Button btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
```

so please tell me how to do this things.?

Comment: your question is unclear!

Comment: use context of activity class like `context.findViewById();`

Comment: can u write some code?

Comment: Fragment to Activity communication?

Comment: well it's wrong, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
Button myBtn = (Button)mContext.findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
```